# any of the software isn't capturing screenshot

Tags: shutter

Well, I was using Screenshot to capture screens for a long time. But now its causing some problems. When I capture first screen shot after restarting my laptop, it go captured fine. But after one screen shot, when I try to capture another one. It goes okay,but when the save screen appears, it shows the previous screen shot I've captured before. 
After capturing the second one 5/6 time, then it shows and saves the 2nd screen. 
I thought to change the software and switched to Shutter, but its causing the same problem too... 
Is this some plugin problem in my distribution or some capturing software causing this problem?

Comment: Same problem here. This also happens with screencast applications.

Comment: I've tested a lot of software but no one worked fine for me :(
still couldn't find any solution to this